# How to execute a migration.sql file from the terminal

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prisma

I need to execute/run a migration file with this path and name in VS Code Typescript project:

```
prisma\migrations\20230208215211_insert_test_data\migration.sql
```

I know I can run a Typescript file that runs a PrismaClient() like this:

```
ts-node myInsertStuff.ts
```

But I have not seen command that runs a file with the '.sql' extention.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
prisma db execute --file ./script.sql --schema schema.prisma
```

you have to install the [Prisma CLI](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-cli)

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed.  based on that I was able to find the docs on that:  https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#db-execute